# rpath link issues with conda-install r-base

Tags: r, conda, conda-forge

I can install r-base with conda, but when I try to start `R` I get an error:

```
dyld[93564]: Library not loaded: '@rpath/libgcc_s.1.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib'
  Reason: tried: '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/lib/../../libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/bin/exec/../../lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/bin/exec/../../../libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/bin/exec/../../lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/bin/exec/../../../libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/R/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alex/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/r-base-split_1659993936932/_build_env/lib/server/libgcc_s.1.dylib' (no such file)
[1]    93564 abort      R
```

I had installed R without conda previously, which I uninstalled, and removed `.Renviron`. How should I install R in this environment?

Comment: I've seen tons of questions about linking problems when people try to run R from conda. Everything normally works fine when you install R from the official releases at https://www.r-project.org/. Is there a reason you really need to use conda? It seems to be way more of a headache than it's worth at least when it comes to R stuff.

Comment: Please show how you install it. Also why is R installed or referencing an environment called `py39`? I would strongly discourage all users from coinstalling R and Python in the same environment.

Comment: @MrFlick I'd blame the "*tons of questions*" you observe to be an epiphenomenon of users installing Anaconda or Miniconda, rather than Miniforge. The problem is that Anaconda has abandoned R, but Conda Forge has embraced it. So, R users ultimately must use Conda Forge, but they mix channels from Anaconda with Conda Forge, and this causes the linking issue. If users all began from Miniforge (Conda Forge-only) from the start, I'd expect these issues would largely subside. And yes, there are legitimate use cases for Conda R environments, e.g., most Snakemake workflows use them.

Comment: @merv that’s helpful to know. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for most Conda dynamic library issues is [**channel mixing**](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). If creating an R environment with Conda, then you should primarily use the **conda-forge** channel.

```bash
conda create -n r41 -c conda-forge r=4.1

## permanently set channel preference
conda activate r41
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
```

Always activate the environment before installing in it and install all packages through `conda`/`mamba`, rather than `install.packages`.